# get tag values from xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

I have an xml file and i want to get exactly second array tag. how can i get this using DOMXpath in php

this is the xml file structure example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>F9B4F4B6-D0C0-10BA-8DB8-35534DD58C23</string>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>frameThickness</key>
        <real>7</real>
        <key>graphicsHeight</key>
        <integer>800</integer>
        <key>graphicsWidth</key>
        <integer>800</integer>
        <key>location</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
      </dict>
    </array>

    <key>base64Data</key>
    <array>
        <string>Image1</string>
        <data>VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==</data>
        <string>Image2</string>
        <data>VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==</data>  
   </array>

  </dict>
</list>
```

i need tags that is inside second array tag this is what i tried so far

```
$xpath_to_base64 = new DOMXpath($dom);
$base64_data = $xpath_to_base64->query("/list/dict/array");

foreach($base64_data as $array)
{
    print_r($base64_data);
}
```

Above return both array tags but i need the only second one. who can i get that
this is what i want to get

```
    </array>
    <key>base64Data</key>
    <array>
        <string>Image1</string>
        <data>VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==</data>
        <string>Image2</string>
        <data>VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==</data>  
   </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$base64_data = $xpath_to_base64->query("/list/dict/array[1]");
```